# Twitter Bootstrap dynamic form inputs aligned in grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am relatively new to Bootstrap and wanted to know how can I incorporate the grid system in my web application.
The problem is my whole form gets loaded dynamically depending on options selected by user and making ajax calls and getting the fields from database.
So till the runtime I am not aware of the fields that may arrive.
I want to build a screen where in the form elements spread out in a 3 columns view where the overflown input fields in one column gets filled in the next columns.
The below image might give a more clear picture:

```
Pic1: Current situation that is happening:
```

[image]

```
Pic2: Next image shows what i want to achieve.
```

[image]

I just got that bootstrap can help to organize the input fields in grid system.
But unable to see how i can achieve this dynamically.
Any pointers or suggestions for the same are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
add control with

```
<div class="box span3">
             //your conrol
        </div>
```

after add control call function xyz()

```
 function xyz() {
        $('.box').each(function () {
            if ($(this).index() % 4 == 0) {
                $(this).css({ 'clear': 'both', 'margin-left': '0' })
            }
        })
    }

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head >
<title></title>
<link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    .box
    {
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        xyz();
    });
    function xyz() {
        $('.box').each(function () {
            if ($(this).index() % 4 == 0) {
                $(this).css({ 'clear': 'both', 'margin-left': '0' })
            }
        })
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="">
    <div class="row-fluid" style="width: 96%; padding: 2%;">
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
        <div class="box span3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But how can i add elements dynamically? As in how will I come to know if the height is full and i need to pass the next control in the next column?

Comment: add control with .box div and after add call xyz() function